# VSCode Intellisense for JS class instances doesn't work

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

when hovering over a class method that is documented in the MDN web docs I don't get the IntelliSense information I need (like parameters and such).

This is a fairly simple example:

```
let audioCtx = new AudioContext(); // VSCode knows AudioContext, so this works
const source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream); // hovering over createMediaStreamSource gives me "any"
```

Here lies the problem. When typing audioCtx and then the dot I'd like to see the available methods. I'm fairly new and have been issues trying to google the solution, so I hope someone can help.

Comment: I get `(method) AudioContext.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStream: MediaStream): MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` when I hover `createMediaStreamSource`

Comment: try restarting the TS server through the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P)

Comment: @GuerricP I don't

Comment: @AndrewGillis I tried that, unfortunately it didn't work